# How to enable telegram node app to keep running endlessly

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I'm building a node Telegram bot using `node-telegram-bot-api` which is amazing so far.
However, I want to listen to messages constantly sent to my bot, so I'm using:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    const Hi = "hi";
    if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(Hi) === 0) {
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id,"Hello dear user");
    } 
});
```

This runs but then gets to the end of the scripts and closes the node app.
Is there a way of keeping it alive without polling?

Comment: Have you tried configuring a server, like [express](https://expressjs.com), or using some CLI tools, like [Forever](https://github.com/foreversd/forever)?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways: 1 PM2, 2 systemd and 3 Docker with --restart="unless-stopped"

**With PM2:**
First Install pm2 with this Command:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

Then Run Your Project

```
pm2 start app.js // or index.js
```

**With Systemd:**
Systemd is a popular init system for Linux, Here's a step-by-step guide on how to do this:

1. Create a systemd service unit file:
   You'll need to create a `.service` file that describes how your bot should be managed by systemd. You can create this file in the `/etc/systemd/system/` directory or in `/etc/systemd/user/` if it's for a specific user. You can use a text editor like `nano` or `vim` to create the file. For example, let's assume you want to create a service for a Python bot called "my_bot":

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/my_bot.service
   ```
2. Add the following content to your `my_bot.service` file, customizing it to your bot's requirements:

   ```ini
   [Unit]
   Description=My Bot Service
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=your_username
   WorkingDirectory=/path/to/bot/directory
   ExecStart=/path/to/your_bot_command
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=10
   StandardOutput=syslog
   StandardError=syslog

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Make sure to replace the following placeholders with your own values:

   - `WorkingDirectory`: The directory where your bot's files are located.
   - `ExecStart`: The command to start your bot. This should be the full path to the bot script or executable.
   - `Restart` and `RestartSec`: These lines define how systemd should handle restarts. In this example, it's set to restart the service always and wait 10 seconds between restarts.
3. Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. Reload systemd to make it aware of the new service:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
5. Start the bot service and enable it to start on boot:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl start my_bot
   sudo systemctl enable my_bot
   ```
6. Check the status of your bot service to ensure it's running:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl status my_bot
   ```

That's it! Your bot should now be running in the background, managed by systemd. You can use `systemctl` commands to start, stop, restart, or check the status of the bot service, making it easy to manage your bot on your server.